# NSLayoutConstraints to center a subview

Tags: ios, objective-c, nslayoutconstraint

I'm trying to set a subview in the center of its superview with constraints.

```
[view addSubview:contentView];

[view addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:contentView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX relatedBy:view toItem:NSLayoutRelationEqual attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX multiplier:1 constant:0]];
[view addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:contentView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterY relatedBy:view toItem:NSLayoutRelationEqual attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterY multiplier:1 constant:0]];
```

[image]

Why wouldn't this work?

More code:

```
UIView *view = [UIView new];
view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = FALSE;
view.backgroundColor = [UIColor orangeColor];

[view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:[view(180)]"
                                                             options:0
                                                             metrics:nil
                                                               views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(view)]];
[view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:[view(100)]"
                                                             options:0
                                                             metrics:nil
                                                               views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(view)]];


UIView *contentView = [UIView new];
contentView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = FALSE;
contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];

// Create the UIButtons and UILabels and add them to contentView

[contentView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|[syncButton][syncLabel]-(10)-[doneButton][doneLabel]"
                                                                    options:NSLayoutFormatAlignAllCenterX metrics:nil
                                                                      views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(syncButton, syncLabel, doneButton, doneLabel)]];

[contentView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|[syncButton]"
                                                                    options:0
                                                                    metrics:nil
                                                                      views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(syncButton, doneButton)]];

[contentView addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:contentView
                                                        attribute:NSLayoutAttributeRight
                                                        relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                           toItem:syncButton
                                                        attribute:NSLayoutAttributeRight
                                                       multiplier:1
                                                         constant:0]];

[contentView addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:contentView
                                                        attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom
                                                        relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                           toItem:doneLabel
                                                        attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom
                                                       multiplier:1
                                                         constant:0]];

[contentView selfLayoutIfNeeded];

DLog(@"contentView: %@", contentView);

[view addSubview:contentView];

[view addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:contentView
                                                 attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX
                                                 relatedBy:view
                                                    toItem:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                 attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX
                                                multiplier:1
                                                  constant:0]];

[view addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:contentView
                                                 attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterY
                                                 relatedBy:view
                                                    toItem:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                 attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterY
                                                multiplier:1
                                                  constant:0]];
```

Log:

```
DEBUG | -[LoginViewController createConfigurePanel] | contentView: <UIView: 0x17e997d0; frame = (-21 -34; 42 68); layer = <CALayer: 0x17e9e4d0>>
```

The contentView has a 2 buttons and 2 labels in it. I add the buttons and labels. I then set the contentView's right attribute to the right attribute of the a button and set the contentView's bottom attribute to the right attribute of the done label since I know that will be the lowest item in the view. This helps give the contentView an intrinsic size.

So the contentView will become as big as it needs to to contain its subviews.

I don't think this could effect the contentView's centering, but at this point I haven't a clue why the centering wouldn't work.

EDIT 2:

I don't think the description or trace provides anything of interest:

```
(lldb) po [[UIWindow keyWindow] recursiveDescription]
<UIWindow: 0x17d947f0; frame = (0 0; 768 1024); autoresize = W+H; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x17d96070>; layer = <UIWindowLayer: 0x17d95770>>
   | <UIView: 0x17eca770; frame = (0 0; 768 1024); transform = [0, 1, -1, 0, 0, 0]; autoresize = W+H; tag = 444; layer = <CALayer: 0x17ecae70>>
   |    | <UIView: 0x17d96cb0; frame = (20 20; 100 180); clipsToBounds = YES; layer = <CALayer: 0x17dd0220>>
   |    |    | <UIView: 0x17d72a00; frame = (-21 -51; 42 102); clipsToBounds = YES; layer = <CALayer: 0x17dd0340>>
   |    |    |    | <GradientButton: 0x17d74b60; baseClass = UIButton; frame = (0 0; 42 29); clipsToBounds = YES; opaque = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x17dd09d0>>
   |    |    |    |    | <UIImageView: 0x17eb9a30; frame = (0 0; 42 29); clipsToBounds = YES; opaque = NO; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x17ec9510>>
   |    |    |    | <UILabel: 0x17ee7970; frame = (5 29; 32 17); text = 'Sync'; clipsToBounds = YES; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x17ee7900>>
   |    |    |    | <GradientButton: 0x17ee7d30; baseClass = UIButton; frame = (0 56; 42 29); clipsToBounds = YES; opaque = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x17ee7e40>>
   |    |    |    |    | <UIImageView: 0x17ebdb90; frame = (0 0; 42 29); clipsToBounds = YES; opaque = NO; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x17ed0cd0>>
   |    |    |    | <UILabel: 0x17ee96f0; frame = (5 85; 32 17); text = 'Sync'; clipsToBounds = YES; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x17ee9680>>

(lldb) po [[UIWindow keyWindow] _autolayoutTrace]

*<UIWindow:0x17d947f0>
|   *<UIView:0x17eca770>
|   |   *<UIView:0x17d96cb0>
|   |   |   *<UIView:0x17d72a00>
|   |   |   |   *<GradientButton:0x17d74b60>
|   |   |   |   |   <UIImageView:0x17eb9a30>
|   |   |   |   *<UILabel:0x17ee7970>
|   |   |   |   *<GradientButton:0x17ee7d30>
|   |   |   |   |   <UIImageView:0x17ebdb90>
|   |   |   |   *<UILabel:0x17ee96f0>
```

Comment: Which views are "view" and "contentView" in your image?

Comment: I'm sorry, view is orange and contentView is blue.

Comment: Are you getting any warnings in the console. Are those views made in IB or in code?

Comment: No warrnings or constraints needing to be broken. I'll add the `UIView` creation.

Comment: There could be a lot of stuff going on right there. Sometimes the frame is {0, 0} but the content still spills out because clipsToBounds isn't set. So centering could work but it centers in a rect size you don't expect. Try some more extensive view tree debugging to see what's really where.

Comment: All widths are set through autolayouts as well? BTW what is the reason you're not using IB, that usually works a lot easier solving these kind of problems.

Comment: In several places in the code you posted, there's `... relatedBy:view toItem:NSLayoutRelationEqual ...`. Those two arguments are reversed. I can't believe that compiles without complaint.

Comment: @DepartamentoB I don't like IB and think in code provides more flexability. Xcode 5 might be better, but I spend time trying to learn it in Xcode 4 and quickly realized I can do it better and faster with code.

Comment: @KenThomases I can't tell which line of code you posted, but I assure you, there is not warning/error/complaining in the log.

Comment: Then the compiler is failing miserably. Just search through the code you posted for "relatedBy:view". It's the last two statements in both of your code snippets.

Answer (score 0):

Put a breakpoint at a point after your view is built up and debug what is being set up in terms of views and layouts. Use the following two debug commands to show what is really going on:

```
po [[UIWindow keyWindow] recursiveDescription]
po [[UIWindow keyWindow] _autolayoutTrace]
```

If you can't figure it out yourself with this information it could still come in handy to us if you add the results to your original question so we can have a deeper look into the problem.

Comment: Ran them, I can't find anything helpful out of it. I added them to the post.